# Downloading Debug Logs in Subscriber Org

Tags: subscriber, debug-logs

Recently my team was given access to a customer's org to investigate an issue. We were able to log into the subscriber's org with using the LMA. We were able to see the debug logs inside our package as we expected. However whenever we tried to download them we kept getting an internal server error on the download. Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: What was the error code, if any? That would be useful to know.

Comment: no error code, the error was on the downloaded file

Comment: downloaded file has "failed - server problem"

Comment: I believe you cannot download the debug logs after using login-as functionality in subscriber's org. Salesforce support team uses the same functionality to log in to the customer's orgs and are unable to download the logs directly. The workaround is to copy the logs and paste them in a text file.